# Parallel lists vs list of class with multiple variables

Tags: java, android

I am creating a list of x,y values for tracking positions. Working on android optimization is very important, so I am wondering which method would be better from a resource usage standpoint.

Method 1:
Create a class(Position) containing an int for x and y, then create a list: positions.

Method 2:
Create parallel lists: positionsX and positionsY.

I am asking because method 1 seems to be the most user friendly for OO coding, but I don't know enough about the inner workings of Java or android and I'm afraid the overhead of the extra class would cancel out any benefits.

Or are they close enough that it doesn't really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference between the two solutions is negligible. Depending on more detailed specifics such as what type of lists (arrays, lists, maps, etc.) and how you are accessing the data will determine which one is negligibly faster.

However, from a readability, OO, and maintainability standpoint, Method 1 wins by a landslide.

Comment: That is what I thought. It kind of makes me wonder why there aren't built in structures for two/three ints(Integer2/Integer3 maybe), it seems that many of the projects I have worked on I have had to created classes to track them myself... anyway, Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: there is the Point Class [linky link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html)

Comment: Usually, it's more readable and equally efficient to write your own classes that assign meaningful, useful _names_ to the fields to describe what they mean.

Comment: After a bit of research I actually found Int2, Int3, and Int4 in Android.Renderscripts which have the functionality and names you would expect, So that's cool, but they also have a few other properties, So I'm just sticking with my own :).

Answer (score 0):

Java on Android has a slow garbage collection. If you create and discard lots of Position objects, your application may have visible pauses when GC kicks in.
If you go with the class solution, you can create object cache inside class to mitigate this problem.

If you use arrays, be careful with iterators and foreach loop: last time I checked, they created a new object for each element.

Anyway, performance difference will only be visible if you create very large amount (like thousands per second) of these objects.